# How to get the webshop page in 2:nd language, with Polylang and Hyyan

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, plugin-polylang

I have moved content from one WP (server) to another. I use WooCommerce, Polylang and Hyyan WooCommerce Polylang Integration. I might have done something wrong in the setup. I have a shop page in Swedish, and it's marked as "webshop page" (in swedish it is 'butikssidan') in the listing of pages. It has version in English but - the english version is not marked "webshop page". How can I mark the other webshop page as "webshop page"?
I looked in the database after where this assignment is done but didn't find ...

Comment: I have been a little unclear - now the problem is actually that the webshop buttons "add to cart" are not set to the language of the product. I have clearly seen the PO-file (at wp-content/languages/plugins/woocommerce-ar.po) for arabic woocommerce but - it has "add to cart" - but it's seemingly unused.